# mysql import large file with huge blob table field

Tags: mysql, import

Hi im trying to import sql file but there is one prblem.
I have field that is LONGBLOB 14MB and when mysql try to execute this query it fails with 
`ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 612: MySQL server has gone away` How can I import such table.

Im using command line to import this file.

Edit:
After dumping just this one row it weights 28MB

Comment: I THINK YOU HAVE TO INCREASE net_buffer_length and max_allowed_packets size in order to proceed

Comment: set max_allowed_packet to a value 32MB more than that is not good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my.ini file, there is a property called max_allowed_packet, it specifies largest possible packet that can be transmitted to or from a mysql client or server. You should set max_allowed_packet property to a higher value. And restart mysql.

If you dont have access to my.ini file use following query

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=524288000;
```

instead of 524288000 enter value as you required

Comment: I don't have access to my.ini file

Comment: Thank you. But `ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 10: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`, I guess this is over